# populate a dropdownlist from another dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 drop down lists, dopdownlint1 and dropdownlist2.

we have another dropdown that should have all the items of dropdownlist1 and 2.

Is there a way to populate the 3rd one from 1st and 2nd instead of going to database and populating 3rd again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC, it's recommended to use `SelectList` to provide data for DropDownList; so, when you fill SelectList1 and SelectList2, you can join them and provide data for third DropDownList.

You should be careful about values which wouldn't be repeated.